# Gridlayout makes its own margin

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, awt

I had been making game with grid gui and I made MyPanel, which extends JPanel to display bg image, and own Buttons. The problem is, when I make gridlayout, which is larger than 12x12 then it makes its own margin:[image]

Image on left is <=13 case and buttons fit perfectly, when in image on right, case >13 there is  **small margin, which I can't get rid of** . Code:

```
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 360, 360);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));
        
        buttons = new Button[size][];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {

            buttons[i] = new Button[size];
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new Button();
                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: " small margin, which I can't get rid of ": where??? maybe if you type your answer twice bold we'll be able to see it

Comment: @gpasch as u can see in the picture on right in left upper corner, there are some buttons, but they don't stick perfectly to start of pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a null layout!

The point of using a layout manager is that the layout manager will determine the size of the panel.

Then you just use `pack()` on the frame and all the components will be displayed at their preferred size.

Also, don't use `Button`, that is an AWT component. Swing components start with `"J"` so you should be using `JButton`.